# HTML border thickness on zoom

Tags: html, css

Hello i got this problem i got website that on 100% zoom looks normal but when i zoom to 110% + borders starts act weird way. On some of the borders thickness is rendered 2x its actual size and some of them are deformed.

[image: Here is the first example]

[image]

Anyone know what could cause this? When i check values on those they are 1px solid unchanged but they are rendered like 2px.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: For those vertical lines im using  <hr>  tag and there are some styles  hr {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
}  nothing fancy.

Comment: Unfortunately this is nothing to do with code, it is part of the browser engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its because of browser, when usinng zoom in browser it will only render how it would look like at choosen zoom level, so if you have 1px border at 110% its 1.1px border. Since you cant show only part of a pixel, it will show either 1px or 2px

Comment: Ok but why its affectig only some of the borders or part of it and not every line?

Comment: well, it has something to do with browser deciding when to show subpixel or not, even different browsers show subpixels different ways, you can try set border to `0.1px` then ff will show it 1px even zoomed but chrome will not show it at all

Answer (score 0):

following up what @pepo_rasta said about pixels i would recommend not using them at all. I would recommend em or some other relative unity to do your borders in for scaleability

have a look at this

[ems v px](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)